# Closed Formulas in a First Order Logic Theory

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

According to wiki a theory (im instered in FOL) is

> is a set of sentences in a formal language. Usually a deductive system
>   is understood from context

It's clearly specificied that we are considering only sentences ( = **closed formulas**) but we **can't** build a theory using open formulas. But why ???

Comment: See the answer to your previous post: [derivation-and-hypothesis-in-first-order-logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2646349/derivation-and-hypothesis-in-first-order-logic).

Answer (score 1):

We can, but open axioms must be read as universally quantified.

See the well-known example of [Tarski's axioms for (elementary) geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_axioms#The_axioms), formulathed in first-order logic with identity, and requiring no set theory (1959):

> the axioms should be read as *universal closures*; hence any free variables should be taken as tacitly universally quantified.

See examples:

> > *Congruence axioms: Reflexivity of Congruence*
> >
> > $xy\equiv yx$,

and so on.

Comment: Nice. But why they must be universally quantified ?

Comment: @Qwerto - because if you want to "read" them existentially quantified, you have to explicitly write it. $(x=0)$ is *true* if we read it as $\exists x (x=0)$ but it is false if we read it $\forall x (x=0)$. Thus, we can omit only one of the quantifier: the "usual convention" is to omit $\forall$.